# Cannot push to ecr from inside a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, amazon-s3

I have a docker container that is supposed to push a built docker container to ECR. To do this, I am using the docker in docker config (which means container is running as privileged). However when I run `$(aws ecr get-login --region <my-region> --no-include-email)`, I get this error:

`` time="2018-07-25T02:36:51.622504500Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /auth returned error: invalid registry endpoint https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v0/\nv2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: dial tcp: lookup <some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: no such host\n v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup <some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: no such host. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry <some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ca.crt" ``


`` time="2018-07-25T02:36:51.622868500Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error" err="invalid registry endpoint https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v0/\nv2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: dial tcp: lookup <some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: no such host\n v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup <some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: no such host. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry <some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/<some id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ca.crt" statusCode=404 ``

any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you ping to anything from inside your docker container? OR can you give output to ping www.google.com from both host and when you do that from inside docker docker container?

Comment: For container, this is the output `PING google.com (172.217.0.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: seq=0 ttl=37 time=15.120 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: seq=1 ttl=37 time=13.718 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: seq=2 ttl=37 time=25.461 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: seq=3 ttl=37 time=12.597 ms`

Comment: @deosha For the host this is the output `PING google.com (172.217.0.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: icmp_seq=0 ttl=251 time=9.924 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=251 time=21.401 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: icmp_seq=2 ttl=251 time=24.902 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: icmp_seq=3 ttl=251 time=28.212 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.0.46: icmp_seq=4 ttl=251 time=14.855 ms`

Comment: Can you push to ECR from host? and Can you ping the ECR repo from Host and container? Also, can you tell if you are using bridge type or host type network setting?